# Error When submit the data into Paypal Express

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I found this error while clicking on the Paypal submit button on checkout page.

Server Error in '/' Application.

The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Source Error:

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.